# Retrieving Contact photo with Zend Gdata with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, contacts, gdata

When querying for contacts I use the code below to retrieve all my contacts

```
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query(
         "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

As I look through each entry of the $feed I can get access to the contactId and according to the Contacts API I should be able to retrieve the picture by doing a GET on the following URL:

http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/contactId

So I use the same mechanism to retrieve contacts and try to get a photo after setting $id:

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query(
         "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/$id");
$entryFeed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

But I get an error "DOMDocument cannot parse XML". Am I doing something wrong? Are there any example docs?

Answer (score 0):

To get the photo use DOMXpath and search for the "//atom:link" tag, then use $gdata->get(href) to grab the photo. Check for the etag attribute for each link, this tells you whether or not there is a profile photo associated with this contact.

```
            $doc = new DOMDocument;
            $doc->recover = true;
            $doc->loadXML($entry->getXML());
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
            $links = $xpath->query('//atom:link');
            foreach($links as $link)  {
                if($link->getAttribute('etag') != "") {
                    $http_response = $gdata->get($link->getAttribute('href'));
                    $rawImage = $http_response->getBody();
                    $fp = fopen("/var/www/profile/$id.jpg", "w");
                    fwrite($fp, $rawImage);
                    fclose($fp);
                    break;
                }
            }
```